# How do I recover data from a partition I resized with GParted?

Tags: partitioning, data-recovery, data-loss

I have an external hard disk with two partitions. I wanted to merge the two partitions with GParted. So I followed the procedure:

1. I saved the data on Partition A.
2. I deleted Partition A.
3. I extended the size of Partition B to the whole drive.

So far so good, but when I re-opened my drive all the data on Partition B was gone! Is there any way to recover it?

Comment: Have you tried rebooting?

Answer (score -1):

if that window or other than linux os .. just delete the partition and format to what kind of partition you love to have.. but if that linux partition emmm .. read this http://gparted.sourceforge.net/display-doc.php?name=help-manual

Comment: How would deleting and formatting the partition help to recover data!?

Comment: here its http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EJdx2ORi3r4

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QGAgpl77Vmc

recover delete files. with photorec